# AnyLogic seems to be giving attractors a random colour. Anyone seen this before? How do I make attractors invisible?

Tags: anylogic

I have a simple DES flow. Agents are moving into nodes but the attractors appear to be showing up with a randomly colored dot. I have never seen this before and can't see any setting for this. Is this an AnyLogic bug, or is there something I'm missing?

Here you can see the nodes. In the top left, I set 10 attractors. Other than that top left node, all nodes, even the ones without colors on the right, are at the default setting (i.e., random). You can see that the left ones have random colored circles. The ones that have an outer circle are occupied with an agent.

[image]

I've never need this behavior before, though I've built dozens of models. Any insight would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After some digging around, I found the answer. The colored circles are the default "agent" visualization. I was using a resource attached to each node that was of type "agent". When I created an empty agent, the circles went away.

Comment: This is correct. You have no control over default agents, but use your own agents instead and you can make them look any way you like. Thx for posting the answer yourself :)